# useContext() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, react-hooks

I'm running into an issue which is super frustrating and I can't figure out whats going on.
I have a simple context as shown here:

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";

export const AppStateContext = createContext();

const AppStateContextProvider = props => {
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState({
    cartOpen: false
  });

  return <AppStateContext.Provider value={{ appState, setAppState }}>{props.children}</AppStateContext.Provider>;
};

export default AppStateContextProvider;
```

I've also wrapped my App in the provider:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./components/App";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { deepPurple, amber } from "@material-ui/core/colors";
import AppStateContextProvider from "./contexts/AppStateContext";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark",
    primary: {
      main: deepPurple[400]
    },
    secondary: {
      main: amber[800]
    }
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <CssBaseline />
    <AppStateContextProvider>
      <App />
    </AppStateContextProvider>
  </ThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

and I'm consuming the context here:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import {
  Grid,
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  CardContent,
  CardActions,
  Divider,
  Container,
  AppBar,
  Toolbar,
  IconButton,
  Tooltip
} from "@material-ui/core";
import ShoppingCartIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ShoppingCart";
import AppStateContext from "../contexts/AppStateContext";

const TopAppBar = props => {
  console.log("context: ", AppStateContext);
  console.log("useContext(context): ", useContext(AppStateContext));

  //   const { appState, setAppState } = useContext(AppStateContext);

  return (
      <AppBar>
      <Toolbar>
        <Tooltip title="View Cart">
          <IconButton>
            <ShoppingCartIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
};

export default TopAppBar;
```

The line of code that is commented out throws an error because `useContext(AppStateContext)` is `undefined`.
The output of the two console logs are this:

```
context:  props => {
  const [appState, setAppState] = Object(react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["useState"])({
    cartOpen: false
  });
  return react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement(App…
useContext(context):  undefined
```

As you can see, the context looks okay, but calling `useContext` on the context returns undefined. So there must be some mistake somewhere but I'm struggling to find it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You are importing `AppStateContextProvider`

change `import AppStateContext from "../contexts/AppStateContext";`

to `import { AppStateContext } from "../contexts/AppStateContext";`

Comment: In my case the export of the _context_ was used in the same line that declared it, with the _provider_ being exported as default in the last line of the context definition file, so I looked for an export in the last line and found only the default one and used that, haha; thanks for reminding me I should `useContext` with an actual _context_