# React - useContext returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

i'm trying to use React Context to manage authentication, but i can't see the value that return the context in PrivateRoute.js

### App.js

```
  render() {
  return (
    <>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Islogin>
      <Header/>
    <Banner/>
     <Switch>
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/index" component={Landing} />
     <PrivateRoute path="/upload" component={Upload} exact />
     <PublicRoute restricted={false} path="/unauth" component={Unauthorized} exact  />
    </Switch>
    </Islogin>
    </BrowserRouter>
  
    </>
  );
}
}
export default App;
```

the console log of isAuthenticated returns undefined

### PrivateRoute.js

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    const isAuthenticated  = useContext(AuthContext)
    console.log(isAuthenticated)
    const [validCredentials, setValidCredentials] = React.useState(false)
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof isAuthenticated === 'boolean') {
            setValidCredentials(isAuthenticated)
        }
    }, [isAuthenticated])
    return (
        // Show the component only when the user is logged in
        // Otherwise, redirect the user to /signin page
        <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            validCredentials  ?
                <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to="/unauth" />
        )} />
    );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

### IsLogin.js

The api call works and the console log shows true.

```
export default function Islogin({ children }) {
    var [auth, setAuth] = React.useState(false)
   React.useEffect(() =>{
        axios.post('/api/auth').then(response => {
            var res = response.data.result;
            console.log("try")
            console.log(res)
            setAuth(res)
        })
    },[])
    
        return (
            <AuthContext.Provider value={auth}>
                {children}
            </AuthContext.Provider>
        )
}
```

Comment: I don't see where useContext is defined.   Is it a function that you created?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60277899/usecontext-returns-undefined might be relevant

Comment: @DJBurb `useContext` is a hook provided by react https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext.

Comment: Where is `AuthContext` defined? Please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to import it at the top of the file that you are using it in (PrivateRoute.js)

Try this:

```
import {useContext} from 'react'
```