# useContext returning udefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm new to React and I'm trying to use Context API. Here is my code:

FormColorContext.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const FormColorContext = React.createContext();

const FormColorProvider = (props) => {
    const [color, setColor] = useState('white')
    
    return (
        <FormColorContext.Provider value={{color}}>
            {props.children}
        </FormColorContext.Provider>
    )
}


export default FormColorProvider
```

dashboard.js

```
import React from 'react';
import FormColorProvider from '../context/FormColorContext';
import DefaultLayout from '../layout/default-layout';
import EmptyDashboardComponent from '../components/Dashboard/EmptyDashboardComponent';
import NewFormComponent from '../components/Dashboard/NewFormComponent';
import ColorSelectorComponent from '../components/Dashboard/ColorSelectorComponent';
import styles from '../styles/dashboard.module.css';


export default function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <div>
      <DefaultLayout>
        <div className={styles.containerMain}>
          <h1 className={styles.headingCenter}>Create a new form</h1>
          <FormColorProvider>
            <ColorSelectorComponent/>
            <NewFormComponent/>
          </FormColorProvider>
        </div>
      </DefaultLayout>
    </div>
  )
}
```

NewFormComponent.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import styles from '../../styles/NewFormComponent.module.css';
import FormColorContext from '../../context/FormColorContext';

export default function NewFormComponent() {
    const color = useContext(FormColorContext);

    console.log(color);
    return (
        <div className={styles.formContainer}>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I made sure that all imports are correct, but for some reason when I try to log color variable I'm getting undefined. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.
Renato

Comment: what is you're project folder structure?

Comment: my project structure: https://ibb.co/jztdHqV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample Example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/petrified-popcorn)

In your Context Provider you are passing an object, so access color like below:

**NewFormComponent.js:**

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import styles from '../../styles/NewFormComponent.module.css';
import {FormColorContext} from '../../context/FormColorContext';

export default function NewFormComponent() {
    const {color} = useContext(FormColorContext);
    console.log(color);
    return (
        <div className={styles.formContainer}>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**FormColorContext.js:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const FormColorContext = React.createContext();

export const  FormColorProvider = (props) => {
    const [color, setColor] = useState('white')
    
    return (
        <FormColorContext.Provider value={{color}}>
            {props.children}
        </FormColorContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

** dashboard.js: **

```
import React from 'react';
import {FormColorProvider} from '../context/FormColorContext';
import DefaultLayout from '../layout/default-layout';
import EmptyDashboardComponent from '../components/Dashboard/EmptyDashboardComponent';
import NewFormComponent from '../components/Dashboard/NewFormComponent';
import ColorSelectorComponent from '../components/Dashboard/ColorSelectorComponent';
import styles from '../styles/dashboard.module.css';


export default function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <div>
      <DefaultLayout>
        <div className={styles.containerMain}>
          <h1 className={styles.headingCenter}>Create a new form</h1>
          <FormColorProvider>
            <ColorSelectorComponent/>
            <NewFormComponent/>
          </FormColorProvider>
        </div>
      </DefaultLayout>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: he's getting `undefined` as `useContext` value!

Comment: after adding { color } I'm getting TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'color' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.

Comment: I made it work, error was combination of missing { color } and missing { } on import because it wasn't default export. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in imports. You import the default value in NewFormComponent.js file. Change the import to  `import {FormColorContext} from '../../context/FormColorContext';`

Moreover, it is a dupliate of [useContext() returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60277899/usecontext-returns-undefined)
you could have googled it)

Comment: I made it work, error was combination of missing { color } and missing { } on import because it wasn't default export. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are welcome) But you don't actually need to destructure context as `{ color }`. You may write `colorContext = useContext(someContext)` and access color later in your code by writing `colorContext.color`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in importing the `FormColorContext` in your `NewFormComponent` and it's passing the `undefined` to `useContext` method and it returns `undefined` too.

here is what you need to do:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import styles from '../../styles/NewFormComponent.module.css';
import FormColorContext from '../context/FormColorContext';

export default function NewFormComponent() {
    // remember to destructure the color variable
    const { color } = useContext(FormColorContext);

    console.log(color);
    return (
        <div className={styles.formContainer}>
        </div>
    )
}
```